# Eslint error when adding rule @typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix

Tags: typescript, eslint

When I add the rule,

```
"@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": [ "error", { "prefixWithI": "always" }]
```

give the following error message:

*Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix' was not found.eslint(@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix)*

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The rule `@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix` has been removed as you can see [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md#enforce-that-interface-names-do-not-begin-with-an-i).

You can achieve the same effect of `[ "error", { "prefixWithI": "always" }]` with the following:

```
{
  "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
    "error",
    {
      "selector": "interface",
      "format": ["PascalCase"],
      "custom": {
        "regex": "^I[A-Z]",
        "match": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've just updated my libraries and was getting the same error -- thanks for the answer :)

Comment: After I did update packages with the command (yarn upgrade-interactive --latest) the error occurred, thank you very much, your answer helped me.

Comment: Hi, where I should put this code?

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is great, though it looks like you can also simply [specify a prefix](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention/#prefix--suffix):

```
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
  "error",
  {
    "selector": "interface",
    "format": ["PascalCase"],
    "prefix": ["I"]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi, where I should put this code?

Comment: This goes under "rules" in your .eslintrc